# How to install python requirements from requirements file for all users on the machine

Tags: python, pip

I need to run a python app from a jenkins job that uses the user "jenkins", for this I require to install a python package named octodns this way (as i need a specific commit they did not put in a live version yet":
/tmp/requirements.txt:
`-e git+https://git@github.com/github/octodns.git@07b8c19acc337efc90391f5024a346ce0956a5be#egg=octodns`

command as root:
`pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt`

```
root@xxx:~# pip freeze |grep octo
-e git+https://git@github.com/github/octodns.git@07b8c19acc337efc90391f5024a346ce0956a5be#egg=octodns
```

```
jenkins@xxx:~$ pip freeze | grep octo
jenkins@xxx:~$
```

trying to run the app as `jenkins`:

```
jenkins:~$ octodns-sync --config-file=/etc/bind/octodns-config.yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/octodns-sync", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2928, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 635, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 943, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'octodns' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Root is able to run it.

I also tried pip install --user jenkins but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so when I used sudo from another user that had sudo permissions and installed this it worked, apparently you need to run as sudo and not as root for some reason(?) that's the only conclusion I could come to from this